# QTextEdit::setPalette is not updating the text color

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I am changing the text color of two QTextEdit widgets along with quite a few other QLineEdits.  This happens whenever I disable or enable the readonly property to make it better visually.

```
QPalette* disablePallete;
QPalette* enabledPallete;
disablePallete->setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::darkGray);
enabledPallete->setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::black);

// disable writing
ui->TextEdit->setPalette(*disablePallete);
// enable writing
ui->TextEdit->setPalette(*enablePallete);
```

This works perfectly on all of my LineEdits the instant I change the palette.

My problem is that the text inside the QTextEdits does not update immediately, and only does so when I click something inside the box, or edit the text.  It glitches too and only updates where the cursor is moved to.

here is an example.

[image]

I got around it by doing this each time.  It forces a repaint on everything.

```
ui->roomDescriptionTextEdit->append("");
ui->roomDescriptionTextEdit->undo();
```

Even though this works, I would like  a less hacky way to update all of the text color on a QTextEdit.

**Does anyone know of a solution?**

Comment: Have you tried `ui->TextEdit->update()`?

Comment: Ya, update() doesn't work.

Comment: What about using style-sheets instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have only QTextEdit and QPushbutton on the form and it is working fine for me. If you won't find the error then please provide you full code.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(_handleClicked(bool)));
}


void MainWindow::_handleClicked(bool ok)
{
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Text,Qt::darkGray);
    ui->textEdit->setPalette(palette);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: I could not find the bug and the code is too large to post here. You motivated me to recreated the project on a much smaller scale similar to yours, and also found it to work correctly as you did.  I cannot isolate the bug on my end YET, however I am going to mark your answer as correct.  Thanks Alexander.

Answer (score 0):

`QTextEdit` can handle rich text and `QTextDocument` controls that. Now properties of `QTextEdit` can control text which doesn't have rich text property set. If some part of text has some property set (color, bold, font, ...) this overrides default values from `QTextEdit`.

So most probably you have pasted rich text into text edit or performed some edit which set rich text values.